# Port forwarding from one interface to another Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, vpn, routing, port-forwarding

I have a windows 10 machine which is has the following setup

LAN: LAN connection to main router (internet)

WifiHotspot: Hotspot setup to broadcast wireless for PS4

VPN: ExpressVPN set up and shared to the hotspot allowing the PS4 to use the VPN.

Plex server bypassed on VPN software to ensure it goes out the standard line (putting Plex via VPN makes it very slow to anyone connecting externally).

While this is working, the PS4 is very slow at connecting to the Plex server as it has to go out via the VPN then back in. What I would like to do is have all connections on the hotspot go to the VPN except port X. Port X should be routed to LANIP:X

Is there any way to set something like this up?

EDIT: As plex is set to bypass the VPN, you cannot access it on 127.0.0.1:X

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for Port Forwarding in Windows which can direct
any incoming TCP connection (IPv4 or IPv6)
from a local port to another local port or even to a port on a remote computer.

This is done using the
[netsh command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-contexts).

The syntax is :

> netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=localaddress listenport=localport connectaddress=destaddress connectport=destport

where

- `listenaddress` – is a local IP address waiting for a connection.
- `listenport` – local listening TCP port (the connection is waited on it).
- `connectaddress` – is a local or remote IP address (or DNS name) to which the incoming connection will be redirected.
- `connectport` – is a TCP port to which the connection from listenport is forwarded to.

For more information see :

- [Port Forwarding in Windows](http://woshub.com/port-forwarding-in-windows/)
- [Windows Netsh Interface Portproxy](https://parsiya.net/blog/2016-06-07-windows-netsh-interface-portproxy/)